associating artifactory users with groups
From the documentation about Add or Remove User from Groups i've learned, that on a user I can use the following data structure in order to add or remove group(s) from users. That is what I need.

    - name: Manage | Patch group assignment for user test
      ansible.builtin.uri:
        url: "http://localhost:8082/access/api/v2/users/test/groups"
        method: PATCH
        headers:
          Authorization: "Bearer {{ login.json.access_token }}"
          Content-Type: "application/json"
        status_code: [200, 201, 409]
        body_format: "json"
        body:
          add:
            - readers
            - writers
          remove: []

Since I put my api call in a ansible-playbook, this will run multiple times.
The running it the first time is fine, and the users is getting associated with the desired groups. Running it twice, it's ending the party.
Contrary to the documentation:

Returns a 400 code in the following cases:



If both add and remove are not provided
If the same value appears in both add and remove lists
If one of the lists contains a non-existent group


Theres another, important 400 error, which isn't mentioned in the documention at all:
Cant add group that is already associated with the user
Do I've to delete every:

user
group
permission target

and re-create them, if I want to update them?
